# How do you do an os.path.join with an array in python?

Tags: python, join, path, operating-system

How do you do an os.path.join with an array in python? Basically, I want to be able to run that command with an array as an argument. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826888/python-os-path-join-on-a-list

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By array I assume you mean list.

```
os.path.join(*parts)
```

The * takes a list (or similar object) and expands it into parameters. Be careful using it, in many situations it will make your code harder to read. But here is makes sense.

Comment: As an aside, you can also use function(**kwargs) to pass a dictionary as a set of keyword arguments. You can also use both forms in a function definition to get any extra arguments, or any extra keyword arguments to the function. You can even use them together.