# Python os.path.join() on a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.path

I can do

```
>>> os.path.join("c:/","home","foo","bar","some.txt")
'c:/home\\foo\\bar\\some.txt'
```

But, when I do

```
>>> s = "c:/,home,foo,bar,some.txt".split(",")
>>> os.path.join(s)
['c:/', 'home', 'foo', 'bar', 'some.txt']
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 255, accepted):

The problem is, `os.path.join` doesn't take a `list` as argument, it has to be separate arguments.

To **unpack the list** into separate arguments required by `join` (and for the record: list was obtained from a string using `split`), **use `*`** - or the 'splat' operator, thus:

```
>>> s = "c:/,home,foo,bar,some.txt".split(",")
>>> os.path.join(*s)
'c:/home\\foo\\bar\\some.txt'
```

Comment: some more context for splat: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: Note that I tried to use this to remove the last part of a full path. It resulted in an [error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693272/errno-2-using-python-shutil-py-no-such-file-or-directory-for-file-destination) (in Mac), as it was missing the first slash at `/Users/...`. To solve it, I added that leading slash manually, in case somebody faces the same problem...

Answer (score 32):

Assuming `join` wasn't designed that way (which it is, as ATOzTOA pointed out), and it only took two parameters, you could still use the built-in `reduce`:

```
>>> reduce(os.path.join,["c:/","home","foo","bar","some.txt"])
'c:/home\\foo\\bar\\some.txt'
```

Same output like:

```
>>> os.path.join(*["c:/","home","foo","bar","some.txt"])
'c:/home\\foo\\bar\\some.txt'
```

Just for completeness and educational reasons (and for other situations where `*` doesn't work).

**Hint for Python 3**

`reduce` was moved to the `functools` module.

Comment: In Python 3 `reduce` was moved to `functools` module in case anyone else was looking for it as I was.

Comment: pity that python walks more and more away from functional style instead of embracing it and opening up. moving `reduce` away to a module is a statement.

Comment: Even in 2.7 one can `from functools import reduce`

Answer (score 18):

I stumbled over the situation where the list might be empty. In that case:

```
os.path.join('', *the_list_with_path_components)
```

Note the first argument, which will not alter the result.

Comment: os.path.join('', *the_list_with_path_components) is not adding the leading slash in python 2.7, i am curious how can i preserve this slash

Answer (score 11):

It's just the method. You're not missing anything. The [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) shows that you can use list unpacking to supply several paths:

```
s = "c:/,home,foo,bar,some.txt".split(",")
os.path.join(*s)
```

Note the `*s` intead of just `s` in `os.path.join(*s)`. Using the asterisk will trigger the unpacking of the list, which means that each list argument will be supplied to the function as a separate argument.

Comment: Better look into your link once more ;-)

Comment: @Greg it is prefered on SO to copy the relevant parts into the answer and not just paste a link, maybe therefore the downvotes

Answer (score 2):

This can be also thought of as a simple map reduce operation if you would like to think of it from a functional programming perspective.

```
import os
folders = [("home",".vim"),("home","zathura")]
[reduce(lambda x,y: os.path.join(x,y), each, "") for each in folders]
```

`reduce` is builtin in Python 2.x. In Python 3.x it has been moved to `itertools` However the accepted the answer is better.

This has been answered below but answering if you have a list of items that needs to be joined.