# How can i use os.path.join in map()

Tags: python

I have a list of directory name and want to add a fixed path before it.
I am aware that, it can be done in two ways, 1) Using for loop and 2) using map() function.

I was able to do using for loop:

```
dirNames = ['dir1', 'dir2']
dirsFullPath = [os.path.join('C:\\', dir) for dir in dirNames]
```

But with map how to pass two parameters i.e. 'C:\' and directory name for every directory name in list.

```
dirsFullPath = map(os.path.join, dirNames) # so where to put 'C:\\' in this line.
```

Comment: No this question is completely different. Although we can accomplish the goal using `functools.partial` but this isn't that complex a situation.

Comment: @a_bhi_9 what makes you think that *this question is completely different*?

Comment: @user3100115, user3100115: One of the answers from "How to do multiple arguments to map function where one remains the same in python?" solves my problem but answer here "How to bind a constant parameter in Python?" is very complicated. Can you remove second link?

Comment: After marking as duplicate, its redirecting to this link 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826888/python-os-path-join-on-a-list' , it does not answers my question precisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a function and an iterable to `map`, for application as simple as this, you can rely on a `lambda` function and the iterable being your list.

```
import os
dirNames = ['dir1', 'dir2']
path_maker = lambda dir_name: os.path.join("C:\\", dir_name)
map(path_maker, dirNames)
```

Refer to the documentation of `map` for further detail, https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

Comment: @a_abhi_9: Thanks a lot!