# Is there a way to combine more than 2 file paths at once?

Tags: python, os.path

I want to combine multiple file maths together, but I end up with nested stuff like `os.path.join(os.path.join(“assets”, “imgs”), “something.png”)`. I was wondering if there’s a cleaner way.

Comment: I think this might be solved for using `reduce` or `split` (depending on the answer you look at): [Python os.path.join() on a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826888/python-os-path-join-on-a-list)

Comment: There is also a [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`os.path.join("assets", "images", "something.png")`

'assets/images/something.png'